# Flutter: Google SignIn without Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I have been trying to find a way to integrate Google Sign-in with flutter without Firebase. I used the package [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and followed this documented [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5WgU6ERZzA)
The problem is that I am only successful in doing this for android. If anyone knows how do this on iOS, it would of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your iOS app separately to your Google Cloud console and get another client ID for your iOS app. Doing that should provide you with a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, and you should add that to your app (don't forget to add it to the Runner as well). The link I will share contains more details on this.

Then make the following change to the `Info.plist` file. Note that you should replace the reverse client id with the value from your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If this does not help, I suggest you follow the steps in [this guide](https://maylau.hashnode.dev/google-signin-without-firebase#heading-ios-project-config):